# How Nic process packets

Tags: digital-communications, network-interface

As packet arrives Nic detect it on its interface like wire/air and than packet is kept in Rx FIFO the on chip memory for further processing like offloading and determining it belong to it after everything using DMA and it's descriptor packet is transmitted to host memory and interrupt is done than kernel manages it. I understand deeply the code and architecture about how kernel manages packet as have workes on Linux kernel source code.

But the only problem i suffer with is NIC i searched a lot tried to read many books but not got what I wanted to know

After arriving on wire, which is first place where packet stream is kept? Is it RX FIFO or something else?

What are the details about its every minute processing that it does during working on a particular packet?

As it have on chip DMA descriptor as it fetches it from host memory, how does it allocate packet to particular descriptor?

Or leave the above questions as i know some of you will not get it only help i want is to know every minute processing undergoes by NIC from when packet arrives on interface to putting it into host memory can anyone broadly explain it here not in summarised way or suggest link of some webpages/book where I can get what I want

I already posted it on many forums but really the webpages/book i got either told about specification of particular network adapter or summary of Nic processing or about interface between kernel/Host Cpu and Nic

Comment: Depends on the specific NIC, and the information you want is probably a trade secret.

Comment: @user253751 but basic standard thing in all processing

Comment: @user312470 - Hi, FYI I have reset your "display name" as your previous one was problematic in English. Thanks.

Comment: @user312470 basic standard thing is what you already read about, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want minute detail, then it might be worth looking at various ethernet mac implementations for fpgas.

eg: https://github.com/yol/ethernet_mac
you could also check out opencores.org

XMOS also has an implementation of a MAC on their multicore microcontrollers. The code might be available for viewing.

I would expect once you've detected the preamble of the mac frame you'd reset the fifo then put the received bytes into it. In parallel you'd probably have a small store for the header bytes. Once you've received the header bytes then you would determine if you continue receiving this frame or ignore it. If you decide to accept the frame then you manage the fifo  and the dma whilst accumulating the frame CRC. Continue until you've received the whole frame then check the CRC. If the CRC is correct, then generate the status and raise an interrupt.

You could store the frame in your fifo until you get a complete packet but then there is the issue of jumbo frames so your fifo would need to be sized to accomodate these. With today's tech that's really not an issue but then you introduce latency in that the dma is performed after the frame is received and you'd need another fifo to be able to receive the next frame whilst the dma is emptying the first. For performance you really want to get the payload onto the main memory as soon as you can. If the frame has an error, then it's up to the main processor to manage - pretty much the buffer gets re-allocated to a new descriptor and we move on.

The control of the whole show would be done by a finite state machine implementing what could be described as a fairly dumb processor. For the receive side basically all it has to do is read the descriptor which tells it what frames it accepts and where in memory to put it. Rinse and repeat.

There's no black magic to it apart from ethernet being pretty fast.